# Generics in Java

Tags: java, comparable

I'm trying to learn concepts of generic programming in Java, but I stuck on one question.Consider these implementations of function max:

1)

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> collection){
    //code
}
```

2)

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(Collection<T> collection){
 //code
}
```

I'm curious to know, what is the difference between them?

Of course, I know, that declaration `Collection<? extends T>` allows to pass subtypes of T as Collection, but what is the use of it in this case, in static method?

The result has to be the same without using bounds, hasn't it?

And what about this `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`?

If you pass subtype of T, it will be okay anyway, because T implements Comparable and  implementation of Comparable will maintain in subtype, so you can use 2) option.

I'm just wondering whether there are some cases, when it's impossible to use 2) option, but possible to use 1)

Comment: Hint: your text becomes much easier to read if you use that concept for vertical spacing; called paragraphs?And what's the point of saving that space character after punctuation marks?You see, you write text to be read. So you should make that as easy as possible for us.

Comment: Sorry, I've not used service for a long time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34605591/1553851

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break this down into parts:

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

This defines the generic bounds of `T` - it can represent any type that is `Comparable` - either because `T` is `Comparable` or because some parent class is. Since that parent class (call it `P`) likely implements `Comparable<P>` rather than `Comparable<T>` it's necessary to use `super` here. It sounds like you know this already.

```
T
```

This is the return type of the method, and can often be specified by the calling context (for instance when you assign the result to a variable). We'll come back to this.

```
Collection<? extends T>
```

This allows you to pass in a `Collection` of `T`s or any subtype of `T` (call it `S`). If you just specified `Collection<T>` you'd *only* be able to pass `Collection<T>` objects and not `Collection<S>` objects.

Putting them all together this lets callers do something like:

```
// notice that max() returns a C, but is assignable to a B
B b = max(new ArrayList<C>());
```

Where `A`, `B`, and `C` are:

```
A implements Comparable<A>
B extends A
C extends B
```

It turns out, since your method returns a `T` directly, that the `Collection<? extends T>` doesn't really matter because you can always assign a child type (`C`) to a parent type (`B`). But if we tweak the method signature slightly to return a type using `T` as a generic this doesn't work:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Collection<T>
    collect(Collection<T> collection)
```

Notice we're now returning a `Collection<T>` - now the `? extends` becomes important - this doesn't compile:

```
Collection<B> b = collect(new ArrayList<C>());
```

Whereas if you change the parameter to `Collection<? extends T>` you loosen the bounds; the return type doesn't have to be the same as the parameter type. You can pass in a `Collection<C>` but because the caller makes `T` mean `B` (since that's the type being expected as the return type) `C` now *extends* `T`, rather than *is* `T`.

So in short, for your method I don't believe you need the `? extends T`, but in some cases you do. More generally if you intend to support subtypes in your generics it's a good idea to do so explicitly, even if it's not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This works with the first version, but not the second:

```
class A implements Comparable<A> {...};
class B extends A {...};

List<B> list = new ArrayList<>();

B maxItem = max(list);
```

In both cases, the type parameter `T` is set to `B` because `list` is a `Collection<B>`.  `B` doesn't implement `Comparable<B>`, however, so it can't satisfy the constraint on `T extends Comparable<T>` in the second declaration.

It works with the first declaration, though, since `A` is a superclass of `B`.

That explains the `Comparable<? super T>`...  The `Collection<? extends T>` is not really necessary here -- I don't think there is any reason for the max method to return a type other than the collection element type T, so `Collection<T>` would be fine.

Comment: Answer is conceise but in pure words: The second implementation sticks to the type T for the Comparable & Collection. The first one enables you to pass Comparables and Collections, which can operate on subtypes of T.

Comment: `B` wouldn't satisfy that constraint, since it implements `Comparable<A>` and `A` does not extend `B`

Comment: Ok, but what is the use of `Collection<? extends T>` ? I mean upper bound

Comment: @MattTimmermans Stole your excellent example for [my extended answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38779774/5221149). *Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery, right?* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To fully understand it, you're missing two versions. Here are all four:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max1(Collection<? extends T> collection){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max2(Collection<T> collection){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max3(Collection<? extends T> collection){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max4(Collection<T> collection){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

To see how they work, I'll steal the [example by @MattTimmermans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38779680/5221149):

```
class A implements Comparable<A> {
    @Override public int compareTo(A that) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
class B extends A {
}
```

Now let's see which of the four max methods work:

```
List<B> list = new ArrayList<>();

B maxItem1  = max1(list);         // T = B (but could be A if result is A, see next line)
A maxItem1a = Test.<A>max1(list); // T = A
B maxItem1b = Test.<B>max1(list); // T = B

B maxItem2  = max2(list);         // compile error

A maxItem3  = max3(list);         // T = A (forced by Comparable<T>)

B maxItem4  = max4(list);         // T = B (forced by Collection<T>)
```

As you can see, for `max3()` and `max4()`, `T` is being forced to a specific type by the lack of a wildcard.

`max2()` doesn't work at all, because there is no `T` that can satisfy both `Comparable<T>` and `Collection<T>`.

As for `max1()`, `T` can be resolved to either `A` or `B`, but if it is resolved to `A`, then assignment must be to a variable of type `A`. If resolved to `B`, assignment can be to either `A` or `B`.
If you don't manually specify a type for `T`, the compiler will choose `B`.

---

Note that since your max method will likely just iterate the collection once, you can even change parameter type to [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), and everything will still work correctly.

This will allow you to find max value for non-collection iterables, such as [`java.nio.file.Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) to find the last file (lexicographically) in a folder *(if that makes sense)*.