# How do these two generic signatures for Collections.binarySearch differ?

Tags: java, generics

Here is the definition of `Collections.binarySearch` in Java:

```
static <T> int binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T> list, T key)
static <T> int binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

How do they differ from the following definitions (which are similar to `Collections.sort`):

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int binarySearch(List<T> list, T key)
static <T> int binarySearch(List<T>, T x, Comparator<? super T>)
```

As I understand it:

The first definition allows you to search for a key of type T among the list of values, whose type is the same or "lower" of some type that knows how to compare either instances of type T or some "above" type.

The second definition allows you to search for a key of type T among a list of values, whose type is the same or "lower" than type T using a `Comparator` that knows how to compare either instances of type T or some "above" type.

Basically, what I do not understand is why aren't list contents enforced to have the same type as the key?

Comment: another way: `<T> int binarySearch(List<T>, Comparable<? super T>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first set of signatures is slightly more general. It works in odd edge-cases, which the second would reject. Consider the case of

```
 import java.sql.Timestamp;  // extends Date implements Comparable<Date> (!)
 import java.util.Date;

 List<Timestamp> timestamps = ...;
 Date key = ...;
 int index = Collections.binarySearch(timestamps, key);
```

This works for the first signature, but would be rejected as a type error under the second (you'd have to convert the `key` into a `Timestamp` first).

This may be a rare thing, but as the example of `Timestamp` and `Date` shows, there are examples of this in the JDK.

Maybe, it helps to remember, that `binarySearch` never needs to compare elements of the lists with other elements of the list. It only ever compares an element of the list with the given `key`, and thus, it makes sense, to require, that the list elements are comparable with the `key` (and not necessarily with each other).

Comment: can't really sort the list if the elements don't compare to each other:)

Comment: @ZhongYu -- How you came up with the sorted list is of no concern to `binarySearch`. If you want to sort the list, you have to be able to compare the list items. But `binarySearch` only wants to search through the list, not sort its elements. That said: of course, binary search won't work, if the order, by which the list is sorted is not compatible to the one used when searching...

Comment: Just speaking practically. But, even if we indulge a little in thought games, it is still necessary that the list elements compare to each other. This is because the element type, `V`, must be a subtype of `Comparable<X>`, and `V` must be a subtype of `X`, therefore `V.compareTo(V)` is possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34780320/2158288 . This is not apparent from the type system, but it must be true if the contracts of `Comparable` are properly implemented, therefore we can reasonably do runtime casts to compare elements with each other.